# Encryption: What is a tag?

Tags: javascript, security, encryption

I am reading through [node-forge documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-forge) and I keep seeing a reference to a 'tag' variable. What is the tag and what is it meant for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the examples given, they're using AES in [Galois/Counter Mode (GCM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode). GCM provides both confidentiality (similar to CTR mode), and also message integrity (similar to if you were using an HMAC in addition to AES).

The tag is the authentication tag. It's computed from each block of ciphertext, and is used to verify no one has tampered with your data.

You can see these lines here:

```
var pass = decipher.finish();
// pass is false if there was a failure (eg: authentication tag didn't match) 
if (pass) {
  // outputs decrypted hex 
  console.log(decipher.output.toHex());
}
```

Where the check is made to see if the authentication tag validated correctly.